# Public SSL for Azure RD Gateway

Tags: ssl

How can I get a public SSL for https://anchorns.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com instead of a self signed SSL?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is not possible:

> You cannot obtain an SSL certificate from a certificate authority (CA) for the cloudapp.net domain

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal